# Delegates and Functions

Tags: .net, vb.net, methods, delegates

I'm trying to make a simple program that add 2 numbers. I have to use delegates but can't make it work.

```
Module Module1
    Public Delegate Sub MathDelegate()
    Public x, y, z As integer

    Sub Main()
        Dim math As MathDelegate()
        Dim Moperator As Double
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 for addition")
        Moperator = Console.ReadLine()
        If Moperator = 1 Then
            math = New MathDelegate(AddressOf FnAdd)
            math()
        End If

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Sub FnAdd()
        x = Console.ReadLine()
        y = Console.ReadLine()
        z = x + y
        Console.WriteLine(z)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: This probably isn't what the assignment meant by using delegates.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Dim math As MathDelegate()
```

Actually declares the variable `math` as an array of `MathDelegate` delegates. Change it to this:

```
Dim math As MathDelegate
```

And your program should run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually declares the variable math as an array of MathDelegate delegates. 
Change it to this:
Dim math As MathDelegate
and then call 
FnAdd() function.